# Looking to Build a QR Generator

Tags: qr-code, code-generation

Can anyone tell me how to go about building a QR generator?  I would like to create custom QR codes for address book entry on mobile phones. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm into it and take to implement one for my company. Share with use anything you found.

Comment: Have you tried to build a QR code generator within an app that doesn't rely on external connection? I am currently using the Google Chart API but that requires the device to access the internet. Note I am asking the same question below to PrashantGupta.

Comment: By the way, I have tried http://www.onbarcode.com/ already but that is not free/open source.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

[1] http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx

[2] http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Personally I prefer zxing. Check this out: http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Have you tried to build a QR code generator within an app that doesn't rely on external connection? I am currently using the Google Chart API but that requires the device to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you on? Here's one for Silverlight / WPF:

http://labs.infragistics.com/silverlightdv/2010.3/#/Samples/Barcode/BarcodeQRCode